# Custom View not adding subviews

Tags: android, android-custom-view

This is my custom view:

```
public class FilterView extends RelativeLayout{

    public FilterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }


    public void init(){
    //To test, I add just a test button that will change the color of the view
        Button b = new Button(getContext());
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) { setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); }
        });
        b.setText("TEST");

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        addView(b, lay);
        //Also have tried without settings the layoutparams...

        setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
```

I add this custom view in an activity like this (with a red background):

```
<com.example.android.FilterView android:id="@+id/filter"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_height="100dip"/>
```

The result is a view of color... BLUE, the one setted in the init(), so the code in init is called well. BUT, the view has nothing inside, its just blue, no button named "TEST", and no area is clickable because the view is not turned green wherever I click

Comment: Maybe you are adding your button outside of your Layout (your device would have very low DPI in this case though). Try calling just `addView(b);` instead of `addView(b, lay);`

Comment: Actually addView(b) is what I had initially, and didn't work either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry I did a terrible mistake,

My custom view was reimplementing onLayout method, and didn't call it's super method... Adding the super solved it. Sorry to bother you for such a stupid question..

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}
```

Comment: Glad you sorted your problem, please accept this answer (when SO lets you that is :P)

Answer (score 0):

complete this line

```
addView(b, lay);
```

with

```
this.addView(b, lay);
```

Comment: and try to add    layaddRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

Comment: ah yes you use an xml so If you add View by xml, then android will implement constructor

public FilterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}  try to put the second constructor public FilterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
} and make a custom construcot that have your init function and call it when you initialize your view in your activity